# How to connect Superset Appache to Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, dashboard, apache-superset

I'm new with Superset Appache and I am using it to make some Dashboards.
Now I want to connect Superset(I'm using "version": "0.0.0-dev") to google sheets, but I can't find it in Databses.

So would you please helpe with this issue ?
Does the version I use support google sheets ?

Thank you

Best regards,
Rachid

Connect Superset to google sheets

Comment: https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/google-sheets/